# Dash Callbacks: multiple outputs showing at different sections in the web app

Tags: python, dataframe, dashboard

I want to get from a call back a DF(DataFrame) and the figure for that same DF, but I want to show each one individually.

I will take this example posted by @Philippe in this [link](https://community.plotly.com/t/multiple-outputs-in-dash-now-available/19437)  just to have something to work with and give some ideas:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_table as dt
import dash_html_components as html

from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

import plotly.graph_objs as go

sample_data = {
    'series': {
        'data': [
            {'title': 'Game of Thrones', 'score': 9.5},
            {'title': 'Stranger Things', 'score': 8.9},
            {'title': 'Vikings', 'score': 8.6}
        ],
        'style': {
            'backgroundColor': '#ff998a'
        }
    },
    'movies': {
        'data': [
            {'title': 'Rambo', 'score': 7.7},
            {'title': 'The Terminator', 'score': 8.0},
            {'title': 'Alien', 'score': 8.5}
        ],
        'style': {
            'backgroundColor': '#fff289'
        }
    }
}

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Multi output example'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='data-dropdown', options=[
        {'label': 'Movies', 'value': 'movies'},
        {'label': 'Series', 'value': 'series'}
    ], value='movies'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
        dt.DataTable(id='data-table', columns=[
            {'name': 'Title', 'id': 'title'},
            {'name': 'Score', 'id': 'score'}
        ])
    ])
], id='container')


@app.callback([
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Output('data-table', 'data'),
    Output('data-table', 'columns'),
    Output('container', 'style')
], [Input('data-dropdown', 'value')])
def multi_output(value):
    if value is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    selected = sample_data[value]
    data = selected['data']
    columns = [
        {'name': k.capitalize(), 'id': k}
        for k in data[0].keys()
    ]
    figure = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Bar(x=[x['score']], text=x['title'], name=x['title'])
            for x in data
        ]
    )

    return figure, data, columns, selected['style']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

In the end a results showing the fig and data of the DataFrame is shown
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBiAX.png).

However, I want to first show the figure. Then I want to use the data from the DF created in the callback to do more calculations and finally display those calculations using a submit button you click on it.

Is this possible?

What I have done so far is using two different callbacks with kind of the same script, but I was wondering if I can used just one callback a save some repetition in the code.

I hope my question is clear, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!I used `dcc.store` here some references if someone need it in the future: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store

My line code was this one:

```
dcc.Store(id='store-data', data=[], storage_type='memory'),
```

Taking from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLykSQNIM1E. Great video created by Youtube Channel: Charming Data